# Higher order IRT model in R

Tags: r

I am trying to estimate a higher order model with the mirt package in R.

I have already conducted analysis using a bi-factor structure.

I have 60 items, the first 30 being one and the second 30 being a second dimensions of my model. I know that these two dimensions are strongly correlated (r =  .8), which was the motivation to estimate a bi-factor model. However, I would like to compare the bi-factor structure to a model in which both subdimensions are explained by a general factor G.

I have troubles finding the correct model specification to estimate the model.

```
`specific <- c(rep(1,30),rep(2,30)) `
model2 <- '
    F1 = 1-60 '
mod <- bfactor(all_data,specific, model2 = model2,itemtype = "Rasch")
```

However this only gives me a model with ageneral factors and two specific factors, essentially a bi-factor model. What I am trying to specify is that (a) the two lower tier factors both load on a general factor, while the lower tier factors are uncorrelated and (b) the same models but allowing the lower tier factors to correlate.

I am happy if someone could help me out here.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think it's not possible to estimated a bifactor model with correlated lower tier factors, as the model would be unidentified. You should be able to estimated (1) a bifactor model with uncorrelated factors and (2) a 2-dimensional model with correlated factors; those two models should yield the exact same fit. However, this entire discussion might be better suited for [stats.stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). Also, the maintainer of the `mirt` package is active there.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for the answer. That is exactly what I have done instead. Do you know any code that would allow me to specify a higher order IRT model, like in this article? DOI: 10.3102/1076998614559419

Comment: I don't know how to do that in `mirt`; I'll be looking forward to an answer from Phil as well. There is a hint on how to do that with `TAM` in the [manual (p 142 ff; example section 17 of the tam.mml method; model 5)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TAM/TAM.pdf); but it is not native available there.

Comment: I have also posted the question on stackexchange so we will hopefully get an answer soon. Thank you for the link though, I suspect model 5 on page 144 is actually a HO-IRT model.

Comment: groups.google.com/g/mirt-package/c/Q6izYN0ab3Y thats the answer